# 'custom_filters' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, filter, django-templates

I'm trying to create custom filters, and I've followed the steps in the Django documention.
However, when I load the template that loads the filters the following error is thrown:

```
'custom_filters' is not a valid tag library
```

...which refers to the line below in the template:

```
1   {% extends 'shared/base.html' %}
2   {% load custom_filters %} <--- the error
3   
4   {% block title %}
5       Showing project {{project}}
6   {% endblock %}
```

**The file structure:**

```
project/
    ...
    ...
    models.py
    views.py
    templates/
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        custom_filters.py
```

**custom_filters.py:**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='ownership')
def ownership(project, user):
    return project.added_by_user == user
```

So, by some reason Django can't find the custom_filters file as it seems, even though I have done everything as one should (as far as I know).

What am I doing wrong?

*NOTE: Of course I've tried to restart the server.*

Comment: Is this in an app? The app that contains the custom tags must be in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template tags folder must be beside of templates folder, views.py, models.py, ...

```
 //Don't forget also to put __init__.py outside the templatetags,

 @register.simple_tag
 def ownership(project, user):
     return project.added_by_user == user
```

Answer (score 1):

If your App name is `MyApp` and your tag folder name is `templatetags` then in `settings.py` you should have :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'MyApp',
'MyApp.templatetags'
```

]

Both your `app` and your `tag folder` which is under your app package
Django Project are needed there.

```
-> MyApp
    ---> models.py
    ---> views.py
    ---> templatetags
      -----> __init__.py
      -----> app_filters.py
```